# Memory layout of C program

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

When I run this C code, I get the following output as shown. What these numbers mean, why they
are like that and what can we learn from it about the position of the variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int i,int j, int *ptr);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int a=2;
 int b=4;
 int *age = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *age =0;
 *age +=a;
 printf("Main Address of local variable a=%u,b=%u and *age=%u and address of dynamic variable %u\n", (unsigned int)&a,(unsigned int)&b,(unsigned int) &age, (unsigned int) age);

f(a,b, age);
 return 0;
}

int f(int i,int j, int *ptr) {
 printf("Function f: address of local variable a=%u,b=%u and address of dynamic variable %u\n (unsigned int) &i,(unsigned int)&j,(unsigned int) ptr);
}
```

Output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/code$ ./var0
Main Address of local variable a=3212861652,b=3212861656 and
*age=3212861660 and address of dynamic variable 158076936
Function f: address of local variable
a=3212861616,b=3212861620 and address of dynamic variable
158076936
```

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is or what you are trying to do with these pointers. If you want to print the address of a printer, use `%p` instead of `%u`.

Comment: What concepts are you trying to understand? This reads like a homework question but I don't know what lessons your professor's testing you on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, memory is laid out as such:

```
High Addresses
--------------
|    Stack    |
---------------
|             |
---------------
|    Heap     |
---------------
| Static Data |
---------------
|    Code     |
---------------
 Low Adresses
```

When you initialize a local variable like `a, b, age`, each variable is allowed to occupy a space on the the stack which is determined by its type. In other words, it gets its own an address on the stack. Notice that because of the way memory is laid out, these variables have higher address values, consistent with the diagram above. Now, understand that the address of `a` is `3212861652` and its value is `2`; the address of `age` is `3212861660`, and its value is `158076936`.

That value of `age` is an address of memory on the heap. That is what is returned by a call to `malloc`. When you `malloc(sizeof(int))`, you're asking for an address on the heap that can be used to store `sizeof(int)` bytes freely. The heap is much lower down, so the value of age is much lower than the address it is stored at.

Comment: Addresses are not necessarily `sizeof(int)`. More than that, pointers of different types can actually have different sizes. Also, `sizeof` produces a number of bytes, not a number of bits.